# In react, how to pass states down as props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

This is a very noob question but I've been trying all day do implement this. Please help me out.
*Sorry for the length, just tried to put out the whole thing I am struggling with*

I am trying to build custom buttons and to do so, I created a component so I can create as many buttons that I want. For that I declared a state and passed down some information as props, which is as follows:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import Button from '../components/Button'

function CustomButton() {

  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false)

  return (
    <div className='CustomButton'>
      <Navbar />
      <Button setClicked={setClicked} name="Button One" clicked={clicked}/>
      <Button setClicked={setClicked} name="Button Two" clicked={clicked}/>
      <Button setClicked={setClicked} name="Button Three" clicked={clicked}/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default CustomButton
```

As you can see, we passed the state and name of that button down. To render this Buttons, following component has been created:

```
import React from 'react'
import Modal from './Modal/Modal'

function Button({setClicked, name, clicked}) {
  return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={() => {setClicked(true)}}>{name}</button>
        {clicked && <Modal closeModal={setClicked} name={`You Clicked ${name}`} />}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Button
```

And lastly, when once a button is clicked, we want to perform some action. That action is to pop the Modal on a screen. And to do so, we created a Modal and passed down few props. Code for the same is as follows:

```
import React from 'react'

function Modal({closeModal, name}) {
  return (
    <div className='modal'>
        <div className='modalContainer'>
          <p>{name}</p>
            <div>
                <button onClick={() => {closeModal(false)}}>&times;</button>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
   )
}

export default Modal
```

The expected result is for a Modal to pop with "You clicked button One", supposing we clicked one[image: expected result] something similar to this.

The actual result is that all three Modals pop up one above the other when any of the three buttons are passed. The result: [image: Actual Result]

I realize that I am passing the states wrong way. When any of the button is clicked all three get set to true. I simply don't realize how. Don't they create a method for each one?

Also, can you guys please teach me a better/understandable way to write *clicked* logic. Like maybe

```
if(clicked){
     <Modal closeModal={setClicked} name={`You Clicked ${name}`} />
}
```

Comment: because you are using same variable for the condition in all modals. Try putting the modal in parent component, and onclick from child buttons trigger parent function to trigger the modal.

Comment: Another problem is that your `<Button>`s...are not buttons! They are all including a `<Modal>` too, giving them too many responsibilities.

Comment: @moonwave99 so I should free them of their responsibilities? That would take calling Modal in CustomButton for every button. My big brain thought maybe it could automate it. Mina does have some excellent solution down there. It's amazing and I am lost in it. It creates addition differences though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you bind all three buttons with one `state`, You need a `state` as array, with items equal to the number of buttons.

```
 const [clicked, setClicked] = useState([false, false, false])

  return (
    <div className='CustomButton'>
      <Navbar />
      {
         clicked.map((button, i) => {
             return <Button setClicked={setClicked} name="Button Three" clicked={clicked[i]} index={i}/>
         })
      }
    </div>
  )
```

Then in the `button` component.

```
function Button({setClicked, name, clicked, index}) {
return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={() => {setClicked(prev => prev.map((item, i) => {
     return i === index ? true : item
   }))}}>{name}</button>
        {clicked && <Modal closeModal={setClicked} name={`You Clicked ${name}`} />}
    </div>
  )
}
```

And the modal component.

```
function Modal({ closeModal, name, index }) {


 return (
    <div className="modal">
      <div className="modalContainer">
        <p>{name}</p>
        <div>
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              closeModal((prev) =>
                prev.map((item, i) => {
                  return i === index ? false : item;
                })
              );
            }}
          >
            &times;
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can find a working example on this link.

https://codesandbox.io/s/old-wood-zgjno9

Comment: Your code is a thing of beauty. I am unable to even comprehend it. It does solve few things in what I am trying to do and break few things I already it. The Modal code you recently updated isn't working for me. Maybe I'll give it a fresh look in the morning and try to make the necessary changes. Thank you for the answer. It helped alot. It didn't completely solved my problem but I'll give it a correct answer as it is maybe actually a correct answer after all and has a better approach. Thanks.

Comment: In Modal component can you please explain closeModal function. How do we get prev value? As far as I understand this is JS and not react specifically. I still can't figure it out.

Comment: You are welcome, What I did is use `state` as an array, So each `button` will have it's own `true/false flag`, to each button has contol on it's value in the array, I should pass the `button` `index`, So when I use `setClicked`, I know which item I should modify by index.

Comment: any `setState` accept a callback as a parameter, this callback will has a parameter with the previous value of the state and should return the new `state`.

Comment: as `closeModal` is a referance to `setClicked` function, So `closeModal((prev) =>
                prev.map((item, i) => {
                  return i === index ? false : item;
                })
              );`

Comment: will `map` the `prev` value of the `clicked` state, and return a new reference after modifying the item value from `true` to `false` to close the `modal` of this `button`

Answer (score 1):

You can implement multiple modals like this:

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [showModal1, setShowModal1] = useState(false);
  const [showModal2, setShowModal2] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={(e) => setShowModal1(true)}>Button 1</button>
      <button onClick={(e) => setShowModal2(true)}>Button 2</button>
      {showModal1 && (
        <Modal text="Modal 1" onClose={(e) => setShowModal1(false)} />
      )}
      {showModal2 && (
        <Modal text="Modal 2" onClose={(e) => setShowModal2(false)} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

const Modal = ({ text, onClose }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {text}
      <button onClick={onClose}>Close</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-grass-btj3zq?file=/src/App.js:0-715)

Comment: Yes, I thought of this too. To create state for every button. And call Modal directly in my CustomButton file. But I thought, what if I wanted to make 10 buttons tommorow. It would be tiresome to do so, and tried to automate it. Couldn't do it.